# What is the Russian word that sounds like "bleen"

Tags: одним-словом, мат

What is the Russian word that sounds like "bleen" that is a mild swear word? Ben Rich (Bald and Bankrupt) suggests that it translates to "bloody hell".

It is said at 6:48 in this video (caution: it has a man defecating, although you can't see anything rude).

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WFQtAhH2B_c

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's *блин*, literally "pancake".

It's a minced oath for *блядь* (literally "whore"), a Russian swear word.

Comment: Thank you, I don't know any Russian but the evidence suggests you are completely right :)
https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD

Comment: Блин is more crêpe than pancake. Pancakes are usually thicker than блины.

Comment: @user31264 depends on who’s cooking. Either way, both are called “блин” in Russian.

Comment: @user31264 That completely depends on where you are. What you're describing are called pancakes in the UK, for example.

Comment: In English, it is more specific than pancake or crêpe - the loanword is *blini*. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blini

Comment: In US, the closest thing to Russian блин is "Swedish pancake" (not French crepe).

Comment: Pancakes are actually called `оладьи` in Russian.

Answer (score 7):

I'm a native Russian. I think, "bleen" is less rude word than "blyat". It sounds more like "shit", "fuck", "damn it". We use "bleen" in our informal speech, and it's OK. No one  will be offended if you use it.
Another thing with "blyat" — we don't use it often, especially with strangers. It's prohibited in formal communication and is considered a bad word in everyday speech. You can easily shock your friends if you use it without any emotional need, i.e. if you're in a bad mood or something really bad has happened.

Comment: @Wilson - It depends upon who, to whom, and at what circumstances. The worst cases are if it is addressed to the police and other authorities. All the cases and the exact articles of the Russian law are enumerated in [this article](https://admmegion.ru/news/343612/), in Russian.

Comment: @Wilson - 'блин' isn't a rude word at all. It's more like 'dude' - we don't use it in formal communication, but you'll haven't any problems if you use it in everyday speech. I cannot imagine the situation, where you can be shamed for this. Maybe you shouldn't use it in a library or in another cultural place. Definitely you will not use it on the Oscar ceremony. But again, for everyday speech it's okay.

Comment: The level of offensiveness of "блин" may be close to that of "damn it", or maybe lower, "darn it". But the other two English swear words you cite are among the rudest words in the language. I think there is a confusion among Russian speakers stemming from the fact that differing cultural rules about where such language is tolerated mean that when American films are dubbed these "unprintable" words are replaced with mild swear words or even non swear words. Perhaps that is why on 95 Квартал they bleep milder Russian swear words but use English "sailor talk" unbleeped in comedy routines.

Answer (score 1):

*Bleen (Блин)* - isn't a swear word. It translates to "pancake". But it has a second meaning - annoyance at the fact that something didn't work out.

*Blyat (Блядь)* translates to "whore", and it has the same meaning as "Блин"

You'll gain a deeper understanding of Russian swear words by trying to translate lyrics [Ленинград - Непросто](https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/leningrad/798456.html)

Answer (score 1):

Gosh, some people say *bleen* when they realize that someone else can hear them and don't want to swear out loud. But since these words sound similar, and *bleen* simply means crêpe/pancake, while the other word means whore, it kind of softens the blow of the latter swearword. *Bleen* is allowed on TV (though not appreciated because it's associated with uneducated speakers) and "blyad'" is forbidden.

I would never translate "bleen" as "bloody hell" though. It's just an "oh, crap!".

Comment: It's just an "Oh crêpe"!!!

Answer (score 0):

I'd say a better (American) English analogy is "frig" for "fuck," or "sugar" for "shit."  It's hinting at the swear word without saying it.  The manifest content of "pancake" has nothing to do with this usage, and no-one would have said "blin" in Russian 150 years ago; it would have been far too rude because the implication would have been clear then too.  It's like "sugar" in English, in having no negative connotation except when used as a euphemism for "shit."

Answer (score -2):

As a native Russian, I agree with the previous contributors. You use “bleen” (блин) instead of “blyad” (блядь), if you don’t want to swear. These words have nothing in common other than the first two letters. “Bleen” is an inoffensive euphemism for “blyad”, used to express disappointment or frustration. It's like saying “darn” in English instead of “damn”. Or rather, saying “darn” instead of “fuck” or “shit”

Comment: Welcome to Russian SE. Keep in mind though that usually answers that provide new information (compared to answers already provided) are one that get upvoted.

Answer (score -2):

Обойдусь без рунглиша, по запросам трудящихся.

Считать, что блин - это "легкое/мягкое/soft" блядь, - большое заблуждение.

Блин - это самодостаточное слово, которое совсем не блядь, не надо путать.

Блядь - это проститутка, женщина, зарабатывающая телом, блудница.

пройдемся по литературе:

> Ежели где уведает блядь, должен донести и, по обличении, таковую выгнать ему веником за завод и з сводницею, а что на них и на том, кого с нею поймают, платья ― все отдать ему, да с хозяина, кто в доме такую держал и не обличил, взять рубль, и из оных половина на богадельню, другая ― профосу. 7. Ежели такая выгнанная блядь или сводня, паки пришед на завод, и будет жить, хотя б и в худе не обличена, оных и хозяина наказать вдвое, ежели ж блядь или сводня будет ремесленного человека жена, и он отстать не похочет, то взять с него за первой [раз] три рубли за несмотрение и жить ее допустить, а за другой раз выгнать с заводу без всякого пременения. Татищев. Наказ комиссару екатеринбургских заводов Федору Неклюдову (1723)

То есть Татищев ясно описывает, как нужно относится к проституции на заводе, и это 1723 год, замечу. Проституция считается аморальной: женщина, ведущая аморальный образ жизни - блядство, и сводница(сутенерша), а также те, кто замешан - хозяин дома свиданий, все должны быть оштрафованы. "Клиент", который пришел к проститутке, должен быть лишён денег и одежды и выгнан в нижнем белье восвояси. Женщины должны быть приобщены к труду на производстве. Если блядь замужняя, то за неё отвечает муж, который так же штрафуется, если хочет чтобы она оставалась его женой.

Блядь - это аморальное. То что нельзя, но хочется. Блядь - хочу, но не могу себе позволить или не позволяю по ряду причин.

> Дом 145, квартира 116, была хорошенькая блядь Надя, ее защищал полицейский!» Блок.

Блядь - это плохо, оценка другого, что это плохо:

> — Давайте про убийство!.. — Эк ведь сюжетик! ― Ну-ка, Фомочка, начни!.. ― Гы-гы… Иду я однажды по шпалам… ― Ну, идешь, блядь… ― «А ночка темная была», да? ― Ну вас на хер… Иду я однажды по шпалам...

Фомочка было начал веселую историю рассказывать, но его перебили, и сказали "блядь",  намекнув на что-то аморальное "Шумел камыш, деревья гнулись, а ночка тёмная была?"(народная песня с романтический-сексуальным, но аморальным смыслом),  на что он ответил, грубостью, указав, что история не аморальная а иная... Ну а дальше было стихотворение, и про "убийство", как заказывали.

> Михно пришел поздно ночью совсем пьяный. ― Ты, блядь, иди, сними сапоги. Не будешь? Ух, блядь! Сапог полетел в мою сторону. Шаламов.

Блядь - слово для выражения негатива, негативного отношения к кому-то или к чему-то.

А вот блин - это наоборот, что-то или что-то очень хорошее, когда хочешь сказать что-то интересное. "Сейчас такой расскажу, блин! Ты, блин, не поверишь!" Либо, что-то, что должно быть интересным, таковым не являющееся: ну, блин.

> Вообще в русской красоте женских лиц мало той правильности и… и несколько на блин сводится… Достоевский.

На блин, в смысле что лица ряда русских барышень были весьма круглые, как блин. Не интересные, то есть.

> ― Полно, пожалуйста, это дремучий семинарист, в котором ненависть-то, как старый блин, зачерствела. Лесков.

Старый чёрствый блин.

> Ни блины, ни преферанс не избегли раздорного веяния, которое грозит надолго утвердиться в нашем обществе. Странно звучат для слуха выражения вроде: «блин административный», «блин судебный» и т. д., а между тем выражения эти отнюдь не выдуманы, а прямо выхвачены из нашей печальной действительности. И, что всего грустнее, выражения эти отнюдь не фигуральные, а согласные с истиной даже по существу. Съешьте блин административный ― и вы убедитесь, что он жирен, вкусен, хотя ложится несколько комом; съешьте блин судебный ― и увидите, что он тощ и как будто припахивает розовым маслом.

Блин - это как раз что-то подаваемое хорошим и интересным, на деле оказывающееся обыденным и безвкусным. Но тут уже проблема в том, кто готовит блины.

Потому что блины - это лакомство, национальное русское, если хотите.

Блины традиционно готовят на праздник весны - Масленицу. Едят их со сметаной, вареньем(джемом), икрой. Блины в отличие от панкейков большие и более тонкие, иногда очень тонкие. Так что блин - это лакомство и праздник, а вовсе не проститука, хотя для кого-то поход к проститутке может быть праздником, но от этого он не станет моральным. Однако блин может быть неудачным - комом, горелым, чёрствым, то есть можно испытать разочарование в желаемом.

Неудача - это блин.

А уже потом неудача стала и блядь, потому что блин, а не наоборот:

> Но и тут неудача, первый блин комом.. 1030. В. П. Авенариус. Бродящие силы. Поветрие (1867)

Резюме:

Блядь - это блудница, проститутка, секс, аморальное, разврат, сладкий, но запретный плод. Чаще употребляется в негативном ключе, либо для создания конфликтной ситуации, с позиции я прав - а ты говно.

Блин - это желаемое, очень интересное, увлекательное, но в тоже время блин может быть комом, старым, чёрствым, чем-то неинтересным, разочарованием, обманутыми ожиданиями и неудачей. Хотя всё это может сочетаться с весельем. Блин - это смешная неожиданность.

Блин - это смешные неловкие ситуации, абсурд, трагикомедия:

> Иван Федорович, хотя и держался справедливости, но на эту пору был голоден и не мог противиться обольщению; взял блин, поставил перед собою книгу и начал есть. И так был занят этим, что даже не заметил, как в классе сделалась вдруг мертвая тишина. Тогда только с ужасом очнулся он, когда страшная рука, протянувшись из фризовой шинели, ухватила его за ухо и вытащила на средину класса. «Подай сюда блин! Подай, говорят тебе, негодяй!» сказал грозный учитель, схватил пальцами масляный блин и выбросил его за окно, строго запретив бегавшим по двору школьникам поднимать его. После этого тут же высек он пребольно Ивана Федоровича по рукам. И дело: руки виноваты, зачем брали, а не другая часть тела. Гоголь.

Блядь - это смешно, но страшно:

> Маленькая девочка подходит к своей бабушке и спрашивает: — Бабушка, а что такое "блядь"? — Ой внученька, "блядь" - это страшное слово! -
> пригрозила бабушка. Через пару минут из-за угла вылетает маленькая
> девочка накрытая простыней и, подняв руки в верх чтобы было страшнее,
> кричит бабушке: — Смотри-и-и-и бабушка, я бляяяяяяяяяядь! Анекдот.

Употребление "Блииин!" в видео вполне соответствует абсурдности и неожиданности ситуации, если бы он сказал "Блядь" - это означало бы его негативное отношение к срущему бомжу, а так, он был весьма толерантен и они вместе посмеялись над произошедшим. "Блин" - разрядило неловкую ситуацию, и не сделала из неё конфликтной.

Comment: So good to see you write in Russian. Great choice!

Comment: Я вынужден был отменить Ваш ответ, так как считаю его очень наивным. Кажется, что его написал человек, который никогда не слышал об эвфемизме. Минус от меня!

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147319/discussion-on-answer-by--what-is-the-russian-word-that-sounds-like-blee); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: Please refrain from discussing matters other than post improvements in the comments. If you want to discuss hidden motives behind users' questions, answers, comments and vote actions, please do so in a private room in the chat, or, better yet, on an instant messaging platform of your choice. Thank you.